# Reducing if statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to keep track of the count of various values in my data. Currently I am using a counter variable for each and using many if statements to find the maximum value at the end.

Can I reduce the number of if-statements in my code?

Here my Code:

```
myApp.service('faceReaderDataService', function () {
    var dominantExpression = "Neutral";
    this.analyzeFaceReaderData = function (emotionArray) {
        var neutral_counter = 0;
        var happy_counter = 0;
        var angry_counter = 0;
        //other emotions like Sad, Disgusted will not be considered
        for (var i = 0; i < emotionArray.length; i++) {
            var Emotion = emotionArray[i].data.FaceReader.Emotion ;
            if (Emotion == "Neutral"){
                neutral_counter += 1;
            }
            else if(Emotion == "Happy"){
                happy_counter += 1;
            }
            else if (Emotion == "Angry"){
                angry_counter += 1;
            }
            else {
                neutral_counter += 1;
            }    
        }

        if (neutral_counter > happy_counter && neutral_counter > angry_counter) {
            dominantExpression = "Neutral";
        }
        else if (happy_counter > neutral_counter && happy_counter > angry_counter) {
            dominantExpression = "Happy";
        }
        else if (angry_counter > neutral_counter && angry_counter > happy_counter | angry_counter == neutral_counter ){
            dominantExpression = "Angry";
        }
        .... //comparing if two are equals

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two arrays. One holds the emotion strings, the other holds the counts. Tally up using the count array. Then find the max value in the count array and use the corresponding index in the string array to find your value.

You also don't need to check for neutral emotions if that is the default.

```
myApp.service('faceReaderDataService', function () {
    var dominantExpression = "Neutral";
    this.analyzeFaceReaderData = function (emotionArray) {

        var emotions = ["Neutral", "Happy", "Angry"];
        var emotionCounts = [0,0,0]

        for (var i = 0; i < emotionArray.length; i++) {
            var Emotion = emotionArray[i].data.FaceReader.Emotion ;

            if(Emotion == emotions[1]){
                emotionCounts[1] += 1;
            }
            else if (Emotion == emotions[2]){
                emotionCounts[2] += 1;
            }
            else {
                emotionCounts[0] += 1;
            }    
        }
        maxCount = Math.max(emotionCounts[0], emotionCounts[1], emotionCounts[2]):
        dominantExpression = emotions[emotionCounts.indexOf(maxCount)];
    }
});
```